# Gerstenhaber bracket for Hochschild cohomology with values in a module

Tags: higher-category-theory, hochschild-cohomology, a-infinity-algebras, obstruction-theory, bimodules

I am currently trying to compute obstructions in a Hochschild cohomology $\mathrm{HH}^* (A,M)$ where $A$ is a $\Bbbk$-algebra and $M$ an $A$-bimodule. The obstruction I am looking at looks a lot like a Gerstenhaber bracket. However, I did not find any good sources or references for a Gerstenhaber bracket from the right on $\mathrm{HH}^*(A,M)$. So now I wanted to in particular ask here if something like that exists.

As I do not necessarily expect a full gerstenhaber bracket I maybe should add that in my case also $M$ has an $A_\infty$-algebra structure, and so a "Gerstenhaber" action of $\mathrm{HH}(A)$ respectively $\mathrm{HH}^* (M)$ would help a lot.

Comment: If you read Gerstenhaber, "The cohomology structure of an associative ring" carefully enough, he defines a left and a right bracket: if $\alpha\in\mathop{\rm HH}^n(A,A)$, $\beta\in \mathop{\rm HH}^m(A,M)$ then $[\alpha,\beta]$ and $[\beta,\alpha]$ are in $\mathop{\rm HH}^{n+m-1}(A,M)$, and differ by a sign $-(-1)^{(n-1)(m-1)}$. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any idea if there is also an option where one can operate from the left via an action on $M$?